# Laravel - Spatie Medial Library

Tags: laravel, intervention, laravel-medialibrary

In my Laravel 5.8 project I'm using `Spatie Media Library` plugin for my images. Now I want to use `Intervention Image` plugin to for some resizing and cropping.

So this is a part of my code:

```
if ($request->input('thumbnail', false)) {
   $automobil->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $request->input('thumbnail')))->toMediaCollection('thumbnail');
}
```

How can I include `Image` class in this code? Or how can I resize it and fit it in properly dimensions? I usually use it like this:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

//Fullsize
$image->move(public_path().'/uploads/'.'/products/'.'/original/',$filename);

$image_resize = Image::make(public_path().'/uploads/'.'/products/'.'/original/'.$filename);
//watermark add
$image_resize->insert(public_path('watermark/watermark.jpg'), 'bottom-right', 300, 50);
$image_resize->fit(1280, 720);
$image_resize->save(public_path('uploads/products/original/' .$filename));
```

but `media library` doesn't let me use it like this because it is saving images in other folder and other database table.

**I don't want to use MediaConversion**

Answer (score 0):

Make a conversion for a large / full size image in your thumbnail collection

```
$mediaItems = $yourModel->getMedia('thumbnail');
$image_resize = Image::make($mediaItems[0]->getPath('yourfullsizeconversion'));
```

Comment: ```if ($request->input('thumbnail', false)) {
$mediaItems = $yourModel->getMedia('thumbnail');
$image_resize = Image::make($mediaItems[0]->getPath('yourfullsizeconversion'));
}```
You mean something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$location = public_path('uploads/products/original/' . $filename);       
$image_resize = Image::make($image)->insert(public_path('watermark/watermark.jpg'), 'bottom-right', 300, 50)->fit(1280, 720)->save($location);// Image save and check image in public/uploads/products/original folder.
```